# Get @1x e @3x iphone icon assets from a @2x iPhone 5 resolution

Tags: ios, iphone, assets

Hi guys i just wanted to ask a question about one procedure that i am using to export 1x and 3X from a 2x iPhone interface, because the photoshop starting project is from an iphone 5 resolution. So what i am doing is reduce each element and icons at 50% for the 1x, and for the 2x i am increasing each element and icons at 150%

Is that right?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Yes, essentially that's correct. You want to enlarge the icons by 50% to 150% of the original 2x value. Of course, it would be nicer to get actual 3x images with increased resolution from the artist.

Comment: Just going to point out that if this is what you're doing, you're basically wasting energy and application space.  Just ship the application with only your @2x artwork and let UIKit do exactly the same thing for you automatically.

Comment: Yes David, i know that iOS do this in automatic but the developer asked me the material 1x, 2x and 3x.

Comment: @David: Photoshop is far better than UIKit at scaling images (both up and down); you can even choose the algorithm that is used depending on what property you want to preserve -- so, it is visually sub-optimal, but possibly not just a waste of space (on the other hand, scaling on the device is a waste of battery)...

Comment: @sergio scaling on the device is done using the graphics processor, so has little or no impact on performance or battery life, particularly when compared to increasing the size of the application by 250%.

Comment: @David: interesting. Could you back up somehow you statement about scaling on the graphics processor having little or no impact on battery life or even performance?

Answer (score 0):

ios documentation, i hope help you, https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/IconMatrix.html

Comment: Hi Ghost Nars, thank you but i already checked this documentation, but does not tell me if i can go from 2x to 1x and 3x. I don't lose resolution after export because i am working with shapes e paths in photoshop, but i just wanted to know if the percentage of reduction and increase that i am using it is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Simple example, you have 20x20 UIImageView,
You need 1x (20x20), 2x (40x40) and 3x (60x60) images

Comment: Hi DoN1cK thanks for your answer. So in that case i am right, because if i reduce 2x 40x40 at 50% i get 1x 20x20, and if i increase 2x 40x40 at 50% i get 3x 60x60.